# Android widget interaction with service

Tags: android, service, widget, onclick, interaction

Hello for all in 2013!

I have following android challenge:

Assume I have an app consisting of an activity and a widget. Both of these provide the same informations as actual as possible - so I have a service mining requested data and sending in message objects to the activity's or widget's handler, if possible. I'm OK with fact it causes large battery consumption and so on, it's not problem.

There are three possible layouts of the widgets. Current layout is determined on the fly (depends on data from the service) and setted via remoteviews.

Now my problem: I want to be able to toggle the service on/off by tapping on the widget. I have implemented PendingIntent as onClickPendingIntent (maybe the name is different, doesn't matter) and onReceive method to handle this one. It works pretty well but only for a while. After widget creation I'm able to trigger the intent by tapping the widget. But after a couple of minutes (nondeterministic) it makes nothing and the intent is not catch in onReceive anymore.
I have found in the log there is an intent ACTION_READY intent received in the widget before it stops responding my events. Is there any way to set the widget to listen for my touches anytime?

I have another problem with widget-zombie. I tried to google some doc about widgets, but not found any suitable document. If the system decide to kill my process, there will be still hanging dead widget UI on the screen. Its not responding any gestures and I guess it is not handling any messages too. Is there some chance to wake this widget programmaticaly (for example from the service)?

I will have second Christmas in two weeks if someone help me.
Lot of thanks!